# although i am getting "succeeded" state in the command history table, the data is not moving

Tags: flume

Could anyone tell me how to verify whether my data is reaching the specified location or not??I am able to issue the command successfully but unable to see the data...i am trying to move my data from local disk to a file in the local disk itself.i am using the following configuration - 
host : text("/home/hadoop/file1.txt") | agentSink("localhost",35853); 
node2 : collectorSource(35853) | collectorSink("file:///home/hadoop/","file2.txt");

Comment: i am getting a console full of following lines -           2011-10-27 13:13:30,528 [Heartbeat] INFO agent.WALAckManager: Retransmitting log.00000087.20111027-114505732+0530.3437438320673.seq after being stale for 60125ms
2011-10-27 13:13:30,528 [Heartbeat] WARN durability.NaiveFileWALManager: There was a race that happend with SENT vs SENDING states

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell exactly:

1. make sure port 35853 is open
2. I guess node2 is on the same machine as the agent (cause you configured the agent to localhost)
3. I'd change the agentSink to console (temporarily) just to make sure the file reading is woking properly
4. use apache-flume users mailing list :-) I found them very responsive and helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable reply..yes, you are right about node2 and the port is also open..i have posted the question on the list..waiting for the reply..:)